# How to reference the Nth column in a named range in Excel for plotting?

Tags: excel, plot, charts, named-ranges

I have a table with, say, 3 rows and 3 columns, the first one being the date and the other two being random data such as below (data start in `A1`):

[image: Date Series1 Series2 Jan 1 10]

I have created the first named range as `'Date'` for `A2:A4` and the second named rage as `'Data'` for `B2:C4`.

I wish to plot `Series1` using the named range. Of course, I could simply plot `Series1` manually with a fixed range, but that does not fit what I need to do.

Most of the documentation I found either refers to single-column named range or does not address the issue of plotting. The closest reply to my question is found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2431381/how-do-i-reference-a-cell-within-excel-named-range) but Excel returns an error when I insert my formula for the plot. Excel returns "This function is incorrect" when I insert `=INDEX(Sheet1!Data,,1)` in the series values, though this works outside of the charting environment.

My question is therefore: **can I use a named range with more than one column when charting and, if so, how do I reference the Nth column?**

EDIT: In my broader use case, the range is dynamic and is defined as `=OFFSET($B$1,0,0,COUNT($B:$B)-1)`. Any solution for plotting should therefore remain purely dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

As you've discovered, you can't use `INDEX()` in the chart range properties. There is a bit of a way round what you want though. If you use the same formula `=INDEX(Sheet1!Data,,1)` in an empty column, then you can then chart that range instead.

You can even then link the column number to another cell, making it dynamic:

[image]

You can also do a similar thing with the series name, although it would perhaps be easier just to extend the data named range to include the header.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time. Your answer does indeed solve one of my questions. However, my use case is a bit more complicated than this and my objectif to provide a minimal working example may have led you astray.

My objective is to have a dynamic named range. If I understand correctly your solution, this would not prevent me from having to manually update the graph. Even having =INDEX(Sheet1:Data;row()>(counta(a:a)-1);I1) would not help as it would fill cells beyond row 5 regardless.

I edited my question to take this special case into account.